# How can i set the images in the Grid View from the firebase storage as name and url of images keeps changing?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I want to retrive multiple Images from firebase storage to the grid view, but accessing the images with the their names or the download url can't be possible as the image name and image download Url in firebase storage keeps changing(as an user upload new picture or deletes the old one), need help..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Vijay! You might want to check out the FileFilter class. If your images are always in the same folder, or are named similarly (always end in '.jpg' for example), you can use a FileFilter to find all the ones whose names match what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks MMAdams .. all the images will be in the same folder, but iam unable to get some required info of File Filter class ..